# Kendo Excel export formatting based on Data in Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an issue in Export Excel using Kendo export. I am using custom Json data different than the one used in kendogrid. Thus i am using `<kendo-excelexport>`

From the dataset i am exporting to excel, i need format the excel based on few values within the dataset. 
Let's say if the value in JSON contains the word "Total" i need to make that cell alone as "BOLD".

Is there a databind method or Export event for the `kendo-excelexport`

I am aware that formatting is possible using Kendogridexport. But for kendo-excelexport, i am not sure.

Please help.